# How to make a table grid in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I want to make a grid with 3 images in a row and then should the next row 
start. How do I that in Flex 4? Are there any controls or can you do it with 
the Repeater? Or am I forced to do some math on my own (modulus here we go again).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a `TileLayout`:

```
<s:DataGroup>
    <s:layout>
        <s:TileLayout />
    </s:layout>
</s:DataGroup>
```

When a line is full, it goes to the next line automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`TileList` and set the columnCount property](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/07/setting-a-specific-number-of-columns-in-a-tilelist-control-in-flex/) = 3.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/07/setting-a-specific-number-of-columns-in-a-tilelist-control-in-flex/ -->
<mx:Application name="TileList_columnCount_test"
        xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        backgroundColor="white">

    <mx:ArrayCollection id="arrColl">
        <mx:source>
            <mx:Array>
                <mx:Object label="One" />
                <mx:Object label="Two" />
                <mx:Object label="Three" />
                <mx:Object label="Four" />
                <mx:Object label="Five" />
                <mx:Object label="Six" />
                <mx:Object label="Seven" />
                <mx:Object label="Eight" />
                <mx:Object label="Nine" />
                <mx:Object label="Ten" />
            </mx:Array>
        </mx:source>
    </mx:ArrayCollection>

    <mx:ApplicationControlBar dock="true">
        <mx:Form styleName="plain">
            <mx:FormItem label="columnCount:">
                <mx:HSlider id="slider"
                        minimum="1"
                        maximum="5"
                        value="5"
                        snapInterval="1"
                        tickInterval="1"
                        liveDragging="true" />
            </mx:FormItem>
        </mx:Form>
    </mx:ApplicationControlBar>

    <mx:TileList id="tileList"
            dataProvider="{arrColl}"
            columnCount="{slider.value}"
            columnWidth="100"
            rowCount="2"
            rowHeight="100"
            verticalScrollPolicy="on" />

</mx:Application>
```